# Find and store arrays of 5 consecutive numbers from a larger sorted array

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm

How would one go about finding smaller arrays with **5** consecutive numbers by iterating over an array with **7 sorted integers**? *(**duplicates** included in the larger array, that is.)*

```
int bigArray[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6}

int arrayOfStraights[4][5] = {
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
   {2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
   {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
}; // big array may, at large, produce four possible straights.
```

Comment: Are the numbers in the `bigArray` consecutive, or could you have something like `{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}`?

Comment: What is the required result/output?

Comment: OT: `int arrayOfStraights[4]` should be `int arrayOfStraights[][5]` or `int arrayOfStraights[4][5]`

Comment: @greybeard The result seems to be the array `arrayOfStraights`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: @MrSmith42 It's okay to ask for an algorithm without posting code.

Comment: @Support Ukraine: Shreing what was tried / researched so far does, most of the times, help to answer a question.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Agree. But it still isn't a requirement to share code when asking about an algorithm. It's not okay to ask for code solving a problem without posting some code but it is fine to ask for a general algorithm without posting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the value at index 0 is N - like

```
A[0] == N
```

then you are looking for the number of times you can make the sequence

```
N, N+1, N+2, N+3, N+4
```

In other words - you are looking for the number of combinations that gives you that sequence.

So all you need is to count (from index 1) the number of times you find N+1, N+2, N+3 and N+4. Then multiply them like:

```
Number_of_sequences = Count(N+1) * Count(N+2) * Count(N+3) * Count(N+4)
```

Then use a simple `for` loop to add that sequence to the result array `Number_of_sequences` times.

Repeat that procedure for all elements in the "big" array.

Example from your big array:

```
Start value 1.
Count(2) = 1
Count(3) = 1
Count(4) = 2
Count(5) = 1

So 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 can be made 1 * 1 * 2 * 1 = 2 times
Add the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 to the result array 2 times.

Start value 2.
Count(3) = 1
Count(4) = 2
Count(5) = 1
Count(6) = 1

So 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 can be made 1 * 2 * 1 * 1 = 2 times
Add the sequence 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 to the result array 2 times.

Start value 3
Count(4) = 2
Count(5) = 1
Count(6) = 1
Count(7) = 0

So 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 can be made 2 * 1 * 1 * 0 = 0 times
Nothing to add to the result array.

and so on ...

In the end you have

1, 2, 3, 4, 5 = 2 times
2, 3, 4, 5, 6 = 2 times
all other = 0 times

and the resulting 2D array will be

int arrayOfStraights[][4] = {
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
   {2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
   {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
};
```

When implementing the algorithm it's likely a good idea to cache the Counts so that you don't need to do `Count(X)` more than one time.

**Edit**

In a comment @Deduplicator proposed a little change that probably will improve the algorithm. At least in cases where the same number occurs several times.

Don't just do the count for N+1, N+2, N+3 and N+4. Also count the number of times N is present (starting from index 0). Then you get the number of sequences by multiplying those 5 numbers.

After that you can skip all the array elements containing the value N.

For instance, you start at index 0 with value N. Count(N) is 42. When done with the first step, you can restart the algorithm from index 42 (0 + 42) instead of restarting from index 1 (as originally described).

Another improvement is to add a special handling of cases where a count is zero. Let's say at index 0 you see

```
Count(N) = 10
Count(N+1) = 20
Count(N+2) = 30
Count(N+3) = 0   <---- zero
```

In such a case you can restart the procedure from index 60 (0 + 10 + 20 + 30).

The control logic will be a little more complicated but performance will improve.

Comment: This seems to assume the number of index combinations is wanted. How so? `arrayOfStraights` shows duplicate *value* entries.

Comment: @greybeard Once the number of combination of a specific sequence is known, the sequences can be added to `arrayOfStraights` in a simple for-loop,

Comment: The algorithm should be single-pass fixed memory.

Comment: @Deduplicator It is... Of course except the result array which can't be "fixed" memory by nature of the task.

Comment: Better start from index 0 and count the N-values too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Count groups of equal values.
2. If the last N groups counted have consecutive values, output the tuple X_0*X_1*...*X_(N-1) times.

You need to keep track of the value of elements of the last group counted, and the counts for the last N groups.
Not that complex, and leads to an efficient single-pass fixed-memory solution.

```
size_t find_combinations(
    int const* a,
    size_t n,
    int(*f)(int, size_t, void const*),
    void const* context
) {
    const size_t N = 6;
    size_t counts[N];
    size_t r = 0, i = 0, length, combinations;
    while (i != n) {
        size_t* p = &counts[(size_t)a[i] % N];
        if (!i || a[i - 1] != a[i])
            length = combinations = 1;
        else if (length == N)
            combinations /= *p;
        else
            ++length;
        *p = 1;
        while (++i != n && a[i] == a[i - 1])
            ++*p;
        combinations *= *p;
        if (length == N) {
            r += combinations;
            if (f)
                f(a[i - 1], combinations, context);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Beware, I have only proved it correct, not run it.

Comment: Fixed that typo.